# How to extract all COMBO values of dropdown with iMacros and PHP

Tags: php, imacros

I need to extract the pricing data from a form. The form contain several `dropdown` options. All combo of options must be extracted.

**Example of the form dropdown:**

```
size => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
type => 1, 2, 3, 4
color => 1, 2, 3
units => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

So this particular product has  420 possible configurations  `size * type * color * units`

How do I write some some sort of loop which will get all possible combinations?

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/food/getPrice.do ATTR=NAME:size CONTENT=#1
```

By the way trying to use `imacros` to select an option by `index` as shown in the example above does not work. I am forced to select by specifying the value (such as: `%1`)

I also tried `SET !DATASOURCE` and imported a `CSV` file but it didn't loop through as I need it to.

--Just to clarify -- I need this kind of output (doesn't have to be in this order, but MUST output all possible combinations):

```
size => 1 type => 1 color => 1 units => 1
size => 1 type => 2 color => 1 units => 1
size => 1 type => 2 color => 2 units => 1
size => 1 type => 2 color => 2 units => 2
size => 1 type => 2 color => 2 units => 2
size => 1 type => 3 color => 1 units => 1
   . . .
```

--Side Note--
If you know of how I can run this `imacro` from a shared server (or `EC2`) please advise. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the cartesian product, which is described here in PHP: [PHP 2D Array output all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516599/php-2d-array-output-all-combinations)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will mark your answer if this works for my situation. Look promising. TY ;)