# Making the most possible sentences from multiple synonyms

Tags: php

I would like to the most possible different sentences from multiple block of words, in php. For example i put in the php code:

"today" "yesturday" | "is" "is not" | "monday" "tuesday"

It would become:

```
today is monday
yesturday is monday
today is not tuesday
yesturday is tuesday
etc...
```

How can i create this in php?

Thank you.

Comment: First thing is to start writing code. Then if you get stuck, ask, but not before.

Comment: Just saying but it's "yesterday"

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP 2D Array output all combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516599/php-2d-array-output-all-combinations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$block1 = array("today", "yesturday" );
$block2 = array("is", "is not");
$block3 = array("monday", "tuesday");

foreach($block1 as $word1) {
    foreach($block2 as $word2) {
        foreach($block3 as $word3) {
            echo $word1.' '.$word2.' '.$word3."\n";
        }
    }
}
```