# Cartesian product of PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

The title may be misleading, but I don`t really know what it is called. I am sorry for that :(

So, I have an array like this

```
$start = array(
    array('waterpark'),
    array('spain','greece'),
    array('1','2','3','4'),
);
```

how do i convert that array to be like this

```
$output = array(
    array('waterpark', 'spain', '1'),
    array('waterpark', 'spain', '2'),
    array('waterpark', 'spain', '3'),
    array('waterpark', 'spain', '4'),
    array('waterpark', 'greece', '1'),
    array('waterpark', 'greece', '2'),
    array('waterpark', 'greece', '3'),
    array('waterpark', 'greece', '4'),
);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is called a Cartesian product.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP 2D Array output all combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516599/php-2d-array-output-all-combinations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use readymade [`Cartesian class`](https://gist.github.com/jwage/11193216) .

Use it like,

```
$output = Cartesian::build($start);
```

Author: [jwage](https://gist.github.com/jwage)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one it will help you,

```
    foreach ($start[0] as $value1) { 
        foreach ($start[1] as $value2) {
            foreach ($start[2] as $value3) {
                $res[] = array($value1,$value2,$value3);
            }
        }
   }
   var_dump($res);
```

Comment: thanks, but i need as function so it can convert as many array as possible